# how to have a GET request made to "/users?<some-query-here>", then all users that meet the query criteria are returned in a JSON array

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

Long-time reader, first-time poster.

I need help. I can't figure out URL parameters ↔ DataBase.

**Situation:**
I put .../users/?role=admin&title=manager into postman

**Expected:**
a json of all the users who are managers and admins.

**Actual:**
My computer blows up.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = USERS_PATH)
@Log4j2
public class UserController
// other code...
  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<User>>  getUserQuery(
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "name") String name,
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "title") String title,
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "roles") String roles,
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "email") String email,
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "password") String password
  ) {
    log.info("Request received for getUserQuery");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.doSomething???(), HttpStatus.OK); // stuff I don't understand yet)
  }
```

**My Question:**
After the controller, what goes into the UserService and UserRepository?

**Extra info:**
I'm using Spring Boot and H2 but may need to swap to PostgreSQL DB later.

I have the code below as a check for unique emails during puts and posts on the service layer, but I couldn't get something similar to work for this issue.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = ?1")
  Optional<User> findUserByEmail(String email);
}
```

**Rant:**
This seems like a super common thing, and I should already know how to do this.  I don't.  I've been reading the internet for like 5 hours.  Still no answer. I learned stuff about Specifications, Querydsl,  @ModelAtribute, DAO, and mapping RequestParams.  However, I couldn't find how to connect the dots.  So, I went full caveman and tried making an @Query parameter using StringBuilder and a bunch of logic...I'm starting to spiral.

Anyway, I would like to avoid specifications & Querydsl. Just use @Query and JPA, but more importantly, I want a clean solution/ best practice.

Comment: Your computer does not "blow up". It produces an exception on the server's console with information.

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: so you want "and" semantics wit all the parameters? (or "or") very nice answer by chaytania, but... there is ["5.1.6 Query By Example"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example), which is *perfect* for that!

Comment: and & or would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working snip. I think there is a problem with your repository. You are using @Query and also out-of-box support for queries.

What goes in Service and repository: The repository layer(repo) classes are used to abstract interactions with the DB.

The service layer interacts with repo layer and do the massaging of the data that the repository layer returns.

`UserEntity`

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "designation")
    private String designation;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;



}
```

`UserRepository`

```
import com.example.code.entity.UserEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

    Optional<UserEntity> findByName(String name);

    List<UserEntity> findByDesignation(String designation);

    Optional<UserEntity> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

`UserService`

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface UserService {
    void createUser(UserDTO userDTO);

    Collection<UserDTO> getUsers(
            String username,
            String designation,
            String email
    );
}
```

`UserServiceImpl`

```
import com.example.code.dto.UserDTO;
import com.example.code.entity.UserEntity;
import com.example.code.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.example.code.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void createUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setName(userDTO.getName());
        userEntity.setDesignation(userDTO.getDesignation());
        userEntity.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<UserDTO> getUsers(String username, String designation, String email) {
        Set<UserDTO> userDTOS = new HashSet<>();
        if( !username.isBlank() && !username.isEmpty() && userRepository.findByName(username).isPresent() ) {
            userDTOS.add(UserMapper.toDto(
                    userRepository.findByName(username).get()
            ));
        }
        if(!designation.isBlank() && !designation.isEmpty()) {
            userDTOS.addAll(
                    userRepository.findByDesignation(designation)
                            .stream()
                            .map(UserMapper::toDto)
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            );
        }

        if( !email.isBlank() &&
                !email.isEmpty() &&
                userRepository.findByEmail(email).isPresent() ) {
            userDTOS.add(UserMapper.toDto(
                    userRepository.findByEmail(email).get()
            ));
        }

        return userDTOS;
    }
}
```

`UserMapper`

```
import com.example.code.dto.UserDTO;
import com.example.code.entity.UserEntity;

public class UserMapper {

    public static UserDTO toDto(UserEntity entity) {
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setName(entity.getName());
        userDTO.setDesignation(entity.getDesignation());
        userDTO.setEmail(entity.getEmail());
        return userDTO;
    }
}
```

`TestController`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody final UserDTO userDTO) {
        try {
            userService.createUser(userDTO);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body("Failure");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<UserDTO>> getUsers(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "designation", required = false) String designation,
            @RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUsers(name, designation, email));
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks awesome.  I'm shutting it down for tonight, but I'll give it a try after work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

[5.1.6 Query By Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example), here we go:

We don't need anything in our repo, since `JpaRepository` "has it already on board"!

Our service would look like:

```
package com.example;

import static org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.exact;
import static org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.ignoreCase;
import static org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.startsWith;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class PersonService {
    @Autowired
    JpaRepository<Person, Long> personRepository;

    public List<Person> find(String name, String title, String roles, String email, String password) {
        Person person = Person.of(name, title, roles, email, password);
        ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher
                .matchingAny()
                .withIgnoreNullValues()
                .withMatcher("name", ignoreCase())
                .withMatcher("title", ignoreCase())
                .withMatcher("roles", ignoreCase())
                .withMatcher("email", ignoreCase())
                .withMatcher("password", exact());
        return personRepository.findAll(Example.of(person, matcher));
    }
} // UN-TESTED, but compilable ;)
```

...but we see: how much "tweaking" is possible with just these five parameters.

[Usage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.usage):

> ...
>
> ##### Query by Example is well suited for several use cases:
>
> - Querying your data store with a set of static or dynamic constraints.
> - Frequent refactoring of the domain objects without worrying about breaking existing queries.
> - Working independently from the underlying data store API.
>
> ##### Query by Example also has several limitations:
>
> - No support for nested or grouped property constraints, such as `firstname = ?0 or (firstname = ?1 and lastname = ?2)`.
> - Only supports starts/contains/ends/regex matching for strings and exact matching for other property types.

Comment: I saw Query by Example while I was researching.  Then saw "No support for nested or grouped property constraints, such as firstname = ?0 or (firstname = ?1 and lastname = ?2)." and figured it wouldn't help me.  I'm excited to try this.  I'm headed to bed, but I'll give it a whirl after work tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: but for "Situation: I put .../users/?role=admin&title=manager into postman

Expected: a json of all the users who are managers and admins." it is not relevant! ;)

Comment: On the line Person person = Person.of(name, title, roles, email, password);
where does the .of come from?  Is that Example.of ?

Comment: the "of" comes from a lombok.allargsconstructor.staticName it's equivalent to new person(..,...) [link](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/AllArgsConstructor.html)

Comment: @CodyMcCarty: but `Person` is also just a "plain object" (with only these properties, i created (only) to make it compilable) of course: ..you'd have to instantiate/obtain one of `your.domain...Person`.

Comment: edit: `..."title", startsWith().ignoreCase() ...` is probably not good (in english: Mr vs. Mrs)!? , so better: `ignoreCase()` or `exact()`

Comment: "Person" (spring sample) > "User"(your code)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of SQL `AND`, `OR` clause should serve your purpose. A sample is given below using a service and repository class.

UserService

```java
    public List<User> doingSomething(String name, String title, String roles, String email,String password) {
        return userRepository.detailQuery(name, title, roles, email,  password);
    }
```

UserRepository

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE (:name is null or u.name = :name) and (:title is null or u.title = :title) and (:roles is null or u.roles = :roles) and (:email is null or u.email = :email) and (:password is null or u.password = :password)")
    List<User> detailQuery(@Param("name") String name,
                           @Param("title") String title,
                           @Param("roles") String roles,
                           @Param("email") String email,
                           @Param("password") String password);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this with having queries as individual params is with JPA's [Query by Example method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)

So your code would look something like this:

**Service**:

```
public List<User> getByExample(User user) {
  return userRepository.findAll(Example.of(user,
      ExampleMatcher.matchingAny().withIgnoreCase()));
}
```

On the controller class, you wouldn't even have to provide the individual params anymore. You just have to provide the User as a parameter to the method. JPA is smart enough to imply the properties of the user from the params you give. So your controller class could simply look something like this instead:

**Controller:**

```
  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<User>>  getUserQuery(User user) {
    log.info("Request received for getUserQuery");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.getByExample(user), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, but I don't know if it's best practices.

**controller:**

```
  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<User>>  getUserQuery(
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "name") String name,
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "title") String title,
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "roles") String roles,
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "email") String email,
      @RequestParam( required = false, name = "password") String password
  ) {
    log.info("Request received for getUserQuery");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.QueryUsers(name, title, roles, email, password), HttpStatus.OK); // stuff I don't understand yet)
  }
```

**Service:**

```
  public List<User> QueryUsers(String name, String title, String roles,String email,String password) {
    if (name == null && title == null && roles == null && email == null && password == null) {
      return userRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Direction.ASC, "id"));
    }

    //TODO: make to lower case

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.addAll(userRepository.findAllUsersByName(name));
    users.addAll(userRepository.findAllUsersByTitle(title));
    users.addAll(userRepository.findAllUsersByRoles(roles));
    users.addAll(userRepository.findAllUsersByEmail(email));
    users.addAll(userRepository.findAllUsersByPassword(password));
    return users;
  }
```

**Repository:**

```
  @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = ?1")
  Collection<? extends User> findAllUsersByName(String name);

  @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.title = ?1")
  Collection<? extends User> findAllUsersByTitle(String title);

  @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.roles = ?1")
  Collection<? extends User> findAllUsersByRoles(String roles);

  @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = ?1")
  Collection<? extends User> findAllUsersByEmail(String email);

  @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = ?1")
  Collection<? extends User> findAllUsersByPassword(String password);
```

Seems to be working, but I need to test it more.